# Need help deciding between a T-test and a Z-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, z-test

This is the question I am working on

"Professor Liberman believes that Donald Trump repeats phrases in his speeches more than previous presidents of the United States. He counted the number of repeated phrases in Trump's 14 most recent speeches. The mean number of repeated phrases per speech across the previous 10 presidents was 5.2, with a standard deviation of 1.3. Is Trump's phrase repetition rate higher than past presidents?"

What type of test would it be?

Comment: Since "number of repeated phrases per speech" and "phrase repetition rate" are not the same things--the latter ought to standardize for the length of the speech--this question looks unanswerable.  Or perhaps it's a trick question and the answer is "you can't apply a test to compare two different things!"

Answer (score 2):

The sample size is small ($n=14$). In such a case, the deciding factor between a t-test and a z-test is whether or not the variance is known, which it isn't. Use the t-test. A one-sided test of whether the mean is $> 5.2$, to be more specific.

Another question is about whether or not the previous presidents' information is also treated as data (rather than known parameters). If so, use a two-sample t-test. However, given the fact that the sample size is not reported, I'm guessing that you're suppose to assume $\mu = 5.2$ and $\sigma = 1.3$

p.s. I'm answering this under the premise of a dichotomous choice: t-test or z-test. In reality, he distribution of the trump's repetitions may be very non-normal, in which case a non-parametric test may be more appropriate.

Comment: +1 ... or possibly a very different parametric test. [It's also possible to argue that we're not in a situation where either random sampling of a population nor randomization to treatment is possible so it's not clear what framework exists for dealing with it as a hypothesis test. Perhaps some argument could be made for this kind of observation by constructing a model of these as some random process but it would need to be carefully made]

Comment: @Glen_b, fair enough, but it could be that the parameters underlying a person's speech patterns (mean, SD of repetitions, for example) reflect stable within-individual characteristics, in which case treating it as a set of IID observations may not be a bad approximation. But, of course, if one had the real data, some scrutiny based on some descriptive analysis would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

If the sample size is small and the population variance is unknown, you should use the $t$-test. On the other hand, if the sample size is large, the $z$-test, with the associated p-value, provides a good alternative.